# Scrolling to the first question

Tags: support, questions, sorting, ios-app

I use the stackexchange app and was wondering if there is a quick way to scroll down all the way to the first question ever asked on Mi Yodeya?

(This question really applies to all the other forums as well)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. But if you use the web version, click on Questions, sort by newest (on top), go to the very bottom and click on the last number ([816 today](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions?page=816&sort=newest)).

Comment: 816? I see 490. (+1, anyway.)

Comment: That depends how many answers per page you ask for - I likely have fewer therefore more pages

Comment: Ah, right, of course.

Answer (score 0):

It's the first post (question or answer), too, so its post number is 1. On the Web, you'd try [`https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1`](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1). I don't know whether that's doable in the app, not having used it.

Comment: (post 1 could have been deleted so this doesn't guarantee you the first available post in general)